# Configure ngnix web server for IBM Websphere Liberty server (Application server)

Tags: nginx, deployment, websphere, websphere-liberty

Currently I have installed IBM websphere liberty server with mobilefirst in production. As client have existing web server which is nginx (free version), client wants to use it as web server.

Nginx will be working as front-facing with public IP. No farming or clustering setting are there on web-server is required.

Is it feasible with nginx -free version ?

Comment: Check this article - [NGINX and WebSphere Application Server](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/nginx-websphere-application-server/), but you should also consider using Apache or IBM HTTP server, which have WebSphere plugins provided.

Comment: Off-topic. Belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

The free version is suitable. It doesn't have built-in session affinity (you have to link in some third-party code), but you said you don't need it. Just follow the whitepapers from either IBM or NGINX that dominate the search results.